# Concat dataframes: give unique names to columns and drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, noaa

I am iterating through monthly weather station data. I can concatenate the files as follows:

```
path = r"D:\NOAA\output\TEST" 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

for filename in all_files:
    print filename # prints D:\NOAA\output\TEST\189501.tave.conus.csv
    df = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)
    concatenated_df = pd.concat(df, axis=1, join='inner')
```

Which results in the following dataframe:

```
     lat      lon     temp    lat      lon     temp    lat      lon    temp
0  24.5625 -81.8125  21.06  24.5625 -81.8125  17.08  24.5625 -81.8125  22.42
1  24.5625 -81.7708  21.06  24.5625 -81.7708  17.08  24.5625 -81.7708  22.47
2  24.5625 -81.7292  21.06  24.5625 -81.7292  17.08  24.5625 -81.7292  22.47
3  24.5625 -81.6875  21.05  24.5625 -81.6875  17.04  24.5625 -81.6875  22.47
4  24.6042 -81.6458  21.06  24.6042 -81.6458  17.08  24.6042 -81.6458  22.45
```

The `lat` and `lon` columns are identical, so I would like to drop those duplicates columns. The `temp` columns are unique to each monthly CSV file. I want to keep all of them, but also give them meaningful column names, taken from the filename, ie:

```
        lat      lon   temp185901   temp185902   temp185903
0    24.5625  -81.8125   21.06        17.08        22.42
1    24.5625  -81.7708   21.06        17.08        22.47
2    24.5625  -81.7292   21.06        17.08        22.47
3    24.5625  -81.6875   21.05        17.04        22.47
4    24.6042  -81.6458   21.06        17.08        22.45
```

I am brand new to Pandas (it seems awesome, but it's a lot to absorb), I would appreciate any help. I think the solutions are in the parameters I use for either the `.concat()`, `.duplicate()`, and `.loc()`.

Example data: ftp://ftp.commissions.leg.state.mn.us/pub/gis/Temp/NOAA/

Comment: Once you have the concatenated dataframe, you can dedupe with 
[df.drop_duplicates](https://geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-drop_duplicates/)

Comment: `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files])`.  Please share a link to the data files if they are publicly available.

Comment: Instead of concatenating dataframes, I would suggest appending if you are going to be using more inbuilt pandas functionality such as sum(), avg() etc etc.[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-mean/)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I added a link to the example data.. As you can see, each csv has around 500,000 rows of data... Eventually I need to calculate data across each lat/lon site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge two columns and set suffixes for others:

```
temp = df1.merge(df2, on=['lat','lon'], suffixes=('185901','185902'))

       lat      lon  temp185901  temp185902
0  24.5625 -81.8125       21.06       17.08
1  24.5625 -81.7708       21.06       17.08
2  24.5625 -81.7292       21.06       17.08
3  24.5625 -81.6875       21.05       17.04
4  24.6042 -81.6458       21.06       17.08
```

Or in a loop

```
temp.merge(df3, on=['lat','lon']).rename(columns={'temp':'temp185903'})

       lat      lon  temp185901  temp185902  temp185903
0  24.5625 -81.8125       21.06       17.08       22.42
1  24.5625 -81.7708       21.06       17.08       22.47
2  24.5625 -81.7292       21.06       17.08       22.47
3  24.5625 -81.6875       21.05       17.04       22.47
4  24.6042 -81.6458       21.06       17.08       22.45
```

---

```
df = []
for filename in all_files:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(filename)
    # if the first loop
    if not list(df):
       df = df1
    else:
       df = df.merge(df1, on=['lat','lon'])
    df.rename(columns={'temp':'temp'+put_numer_from_filename}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I tried to use your logic within the context of the code I posted, so: `df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)` and on the next line `frame = df.merge(df, on=['lat','lon'])` instead of the concat method. And that returns something that looks like yours, but is not.. It has lat, lon, it adds suffixes for columns if I hard code them in like you did, I just left that parameter off for now, but I only get 2 temperature columns, and they are duplicate data... not unique, so: 22.42, 22.42 in the first row, like it only took the last dataset (temp185903 ) and wrote it twice

Comment: What you posted is exactly what I am looking for, I'm just not able to translate what you have to what I posted...

Comment: @CCantey I've added to the answer code, how I see it

Comment: So the updated code makes perfect sense, but I'm getting `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous` after the first pass

Comment: It seems to be working now, but the final df only has records from the initial pass and the temp names have not changed... So the out put is lat: 24.5625, lon: -81.8125, temp: 21.06... Which is the first dataframe..... So it's like its not merging, or the merge isn't working like I think it should, ie adding temp columns to the right.. and on the name thing, if I `df.rename(columns={'temp':'temp'+filename[20:26]})` in the shell, it shows me lat, lon, temp189503, not sure why its not renaming in script

Comment: and if i type `df.merge(df1, on=['lat','lon']).rename(columns={'temp':'temp185903'})` into the shell after a run, it does append the last df as expected (doesn't rename though)... Not sure why its not working in loop..

Answer (score 0):

this appends new data to the concatenated dataframe as new rows with a column 'date' to indicate which file the data came from. Amend the logic to get the date from the filename.

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'D:\NOAA\output\TEST'
all_files = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')

df_concat = pd.DataFrame()

for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['date'] = file #ammend the variable file to get the date from your file names

    df_concat = df_concat.append(df)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the lat/lon pairs are points on a map. There are 500,000 lat/lon records (points), that make up a 5km grid of the US. And there are 2632 monthly records (each a CSV file from 1895-present) for every point. So just appending would make a file 1.3 billion records long, and I don't see how I could summarize the data for each point.... I would like to the analyze the data for every point - 1 row of data.

Comment: Actually, it's quite easy, all you need is df.groupby(['lat', 'lon']).